# Unsafe in VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, bitmap, unsafe

I need to pass a function C# to VB.NET, but in C# I have something like that:

```
unsafe
{
    byte* pSmall = (byte*)(void*)smallData.Scan0;
    byte* pBig = (byte*)(void*)bigData.Scan0;

    int smallOffset = smallStride - smallBmp.Width * 3;
    int bigOffset = bigStride - bigBmp.Width * 3;

    bool matchFound = true;
    ....
}
```

I read in some blogs that "unsafe" does not exist in VB.Net. The question is: What can I use instead of `unsafe`?

Answer (score 4):

The blogs you've read are correct in that there is no way to use unsafe code in VB.NET. It seems like you want to manipulate (possibly read pixel data?) of a bitmap file. In C#, you can use the unsafe code to get great performance increase over the `GetPixel` method. In VB.NET, you could try looking into [LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits.aspx) instead.

There's an example on [this page](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_lockbits_image.html) of how to use it.

```vb
Public g_RowSizeBytes As Integer
Public g_PixBytes() As Byte

Private m_BitmapData As BitmapData

' Lock the bitmap's data.
Public Sub LockBitmap(ByVal bm As Bitmap)
    ' Lock the bitmap data.
    Dim bounds As Rectangle = New Rectangle( _
        0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height)
    m_BitmapData = bm.LockBits(bounds, _
        Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, _
        Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
    g_RowSizeBytes = m_BitmapData.Stride

    ' Allocate room for the data.
    Dim total_size As Integer = m_BitmapData.Stride * _
        m_BitmapData.Height
    ReDim g_PixBytes(total_size)

    ' Copy the data into the g_PixBytes array.
    Marshal.Copy(m_BitmapData.Scan0, g_PixBytes, _
        0, total_size)
End Sub
```

The page also shows how to unlock the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

That's a what I think could be a working version:

```vb
Dim pSmall As Pointer(Of Byte) = CType(CType(smallData.Scan0, 
    Pointer(Of System.Void)), Pointer(Of Byte))

Dim pBig As Pointer(Of Byte) = CType(CType(bigData.Scan0, 
    Pointer(Of System.Void)), Pointer(Of Byte))

Dim smallOffset As Integer = smallStride - smallBmp.Width * 3
Dim bigOffset As Integer = bigStride - bigBmp.Width * 3

Dim matchFound As Boolean = True
```